# find the limit for Integral

Tags: integration, limits

I tried to find the limit of this function, without any success,

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\displaystyle \left(\int _{10}^x\frac{e^{\sqrt{t}}}{t}dt\right)^2}{e^x}$$

I tried to solve it by L'Hôpital's rule  $\left(\frac{\infty }{\infty }\right)$ but there is no way to do it.

Comment: What's squared? The integrand or the integral?

Comment: The integral, edited, sorry.

Comment: Now what's squared?

Comment: @math110 edited again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use L'Hospital's rule as follows:
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\displaystyle \int _{10}^x\frac{e^{\sqrt{t}}}{t}dt}{e^{x/2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\frac{e^\sqrt{x}}{x}}{\frac12e^{x/2}}=0.$$
The first equality is due to the fundamental theorem of calculus: $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x_0}^xf(t)dt=f(x),\text{when }f\text{ is continuous.}$$
The second one is due to the fact that $xe^{x/2}$ goes much faster than $e^\sqrt x$.

Comment: Thanks but what about the squared? can i ignore it?

Comment: @Matan $0^2 = 0$

Comment: @EclipseSun,you answer is more simple+1

Comment: @EclipseSun. May I suggest you add to your nice answer that the FTC is used. I suppose it could help th OP. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici ok

Answer (score 2):

Hint
$$e^{\sqrt{t}}\le e^{\sqrt{x}},t<x$$
then we have
$$\left(\int_{10}^{x}\dfrac{e^{\sqrt{t}}}{t}dt\right)^2\le e^{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot\left(\int_{10}^{x}\dfrac{1}{t}dt\right)^2=e^{2\sqrt{x}}(\ln{x}-\ln{10})^2$$
and Note this limits
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{\ln^2{x}}{e^{x-2\sqrt{x}}}=0$$
then you limits is equal $0$

Comment: I don't understand, what did you do with the Integral? thanks

Comment: Now I have add some hints

Comment: nice! but is it legal to do such this thing?, you take out e from the integral. :(

Comment: It is  clear legal

Comment: could you explain why please?

Comment: do you known this well known?  if $f,g>0,x\in[a,b]$ and such $f(x)<M$,then have $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx\le M\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$$

Comment: We never learned it, good to know. thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25286/discussion-between-matan-and-math110).